# res.redirect() hanging on first submit

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a weird issue that I can only replicate with certain users. When logging in using activedirectory (https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory) only on google chrome, the first time they click login the res.redirect won't work. If they wait for a second and hit enter or click again, it goes through and as long as they don't close chrome, they can log in and out as much as they want without any issues. A large majority of my users can log in with no issues ever.

I am posting the login from a form, not AJAX, there are some promises, that all return the correct values when I debug so I know they are not part of the issue. Has anyone experienced this before?

```
app.post('/login',
    function(req, res) {
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        ad.authenticate(username.toLowerCase()+config.adDomain, password, function(err,auth) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
                res.render('login.ejs', {  
                    login: false,
                    message: true
                });
            } else {
                if(auth) {
                    if (req.body.remember) {
                      req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
                    } else {
                      req.session.cookie.expires = false;
                    }
                    req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
                    req.session.username = username;
                    let namePromise = ADRequests.getUserFullName(username);
                    namePromise.then(function(fullName) {
                        let setUserInfo = Users.checkUserExists(username,fullName);
                        let seedPTO = PTO.SeedIntialPTOLogin(username);
                        Promise.all([setUserInfo, seedPTO]).then(values => {
                            res.redirect('/');
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    res.render('login.ejs', {  
                        login: false,
                        message: true
                    });
                }
            }
        });  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

catching the exception will help you better to understand the flow, 
I prefer to add the `catch` method after `then`

Comment: Unfortunately, a try-catch did not catch anything. The redirect hung and nothing showed up in logging.